# Merging lists in a loop

Tags: python

I iterate through a list of dictionaries ,in which a particular maps to a list.

```
[{..'ccy'=['a','b']....},{...'ccy'=['c','d']....},{....'ccy'=['e']....}].
```

How do I merge the lists corresponding to the 'ccy' key,while looping through the list of dictionaries?
Expected output:

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Preferrably a one-liner solution.

Comment: Your sets are `{'ccy'=['a','b']}` or `{'ccy':['a','b']}` it confuses me.

Comment: `list(itertools.chain(*[i['ccy'] for i in c]))` https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *nested comprehension*:

```
lst = [{'ccy':['a','b']},{'ccy':['c','d']},{'ccy':['e']}]

r = [i for d in lst for i in d.get('ccy', [])]
print(r)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

The `dict.get` method ensures an empty list is returned in the case a dictionary has no key `'ccy'` (courtesy @tobias_k)

Comment: Maybe use `d.get("ccy", [])` in case some dicts don't have `ccy`

Comment: @tobias_k Good point.

Comment: `r = [i for d in lst if 'ccy' in d for i in d['ccy']]` is kinda faster, but I get that some prefere the `.get()`

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate over a bunch of things, and "accumulate" an answer?

This sounds like a job for **sum,** a [Python built-in!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum)

```
some_dicts = [
        {'ccy':['a','b']},
        {'ccy':['c','d']},
        {'ccy':['e']},
        {'no ccy here!': ['fu']},
    ]

ccy = sum([d.get('ccy',[]) for d in some_dicts], [])
print(ccy)
```